# Is there a way to get the values of outer loops when using nested loops in html?

Tags: html, nested-loops

Currently the id of the popup is used repeatedly and the Edit button only works inside the first "project" . I would like to use the values of the outer loops as well to create a unique id for the popup. Are there better ways to do this?

The current layout lists all projects inside each project all the orders and inside each order the line items.

Example:

```
PROJECT NAME
   --> ORDER NUMBER
      --> LINE ITEM
      --> LINE ITEM
   --> ORDER NUMBER
      --> LINE ITEM
      --> LINE ITEM
```

Here is my code:

```
{% for project in projects %}
  ...

  {% for order in project.orders %}
    ...
    
    {% for lineItem in order.line_items %}
    <td>
      <button onclick="editRow(this, '{{ loop.index }}'), openPopup('{{ loop.index }}')" class="remove-button" style="background: #00e50b">Edit</button>
      <div class="popup" id="popup{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="popup-content">
          <h2 style='color: #000000'>Edit New ETA / Comments</h2>
          <form action="/manage_stock" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            ...
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    {% endfor %}

    ...
  {% endfor %}

  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What template language is this. Btw, most probably you should be able to use the project and order variables inside the innermost loop

Comment: HTML does not have loops. HTML is strictly page markup. The loops in your example, like `{% for project in projects %}`, are part of a templating language that generates HTML. It looks like it may be Twig, but we need to know for sure.

Comment: I think its Jinja? When trying to use the .parent variable I get this error. ``` jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'jinja2.runtime.LoopContext object' has no attribute 'parent' ```

Comment: How would I be able to use the project and order variables in the outer loops? I tried project.loop.index but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loop.parent.loop.index` and/or `loop.parent.loop.parent.loop.index` to access to outer loop indexes for Twig

#### EDIT

So, if you are using *Jinja* and it doesn't support parent loop index, you can try to save it in a variable:

```twig
{% for project in projects %}

   {% set project_index = loop.index %}

   {% for order in project.orders %}

      {% set order_index = loop.index %}
    
      {% for lineItem in order.line_items %}

      Composite index: {{ project_index }}-{{ order_index }}-{{ loop.index }} 

      {% endfor %}

   {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I Get this error ```jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'jinja2.runtime.LoopContext object' has no attribute 'parent'```

Comment: I have assumed it was Twig, I have posted an alternative solution now

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pippo, I'll have a go at this and come back to you.